# Count Persons in tree of Groups with a single query

Tags: sqlite, android-sqlite, android-room, common-table-expression

I'm writing a query in `SQLite`, for `Android`, with a schema like this (extremely simplified here, just the fields I need)

```
GROUP
group_id primary_key, 
parent_group_id nullable

PERSON
person_id primary_key,
parent_group
```

I need to count the number of `person`s in a `group` and in its descendant `group`s, given the `group_id` of the `group` I want to count for. I think I need a CTE query and I've been reading all morning about them, but I'm not grasping how they work.

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track with needing a CTE. Something like:

```sql
WITH tree AS
  (SELECT g.group_id AS root,
          g.group_id AS parent,
          p.person_id AS person
   FROM "group" AS g
   LEFT JOIN person AS p ON g.group_id = p.parent_group
   WHERE g.group_id = @desired_group
 UNION ALL
   SELECT t.root, g.group_id, p.person_id
   FROM tree AS t
   JOIN "group" AS g ON t.parent = g.parent_group_id
   LEFT JOIN person AS p on g.group_id = p.parent_group)
SELECT count(DISTINCT person)
FROM tree;
```

Start by selecting the desired group and its members, and then recursively select all members of groups with the given parent group. Finally, count all the unique users that were found.

[db<>fiddle example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=c651dadda1df2159c35cc0adff6ab5de).

Answer (score 0):

I powered through all the articles I could find and via a lot of trials and errors, I got here (please note that in my real database `person` is `model`):

```
WITH RECURSIVE is_in_group(group_id, group_name, parent_group_id) AS(
    SELECT gr.group_id, gr.group_name, gr.parent_group_id FROM _group as gr WHERE gr.group_id = :groupId
    UNION ALL
    SELECT g.group_id, g.group_name, g.parent_group_id FROM _group as g
    JOIN is_in_group as c ON g.parent_group_id = c.group_id
    )
    SELECT q.group_id, q.group_name, count(m.model_id) as model_count FROM is_in_group as q
    LEFT JOIN _model m ON m.parent_group_id = group_id
    GROUP BY q.group_id
```

This will give me a list of `group`s (including the root one), with a `group_id`, `group_name` and a `model_count` of `model`s in each `group`. With this I can simply `sum` to get the total or look at the row with the searched `group_id` to know how many `model`s are just in this `group`.